# Laravel Custom Exception is giving me Undefined property::$headers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am working on an exception right now in laravel giving a weird behavior that I have not seen before and can't seem to find much information about. I am getting this error message Undefined property: App\Exceptions\UserNotApproved::$headers. Not sure whats going.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class UserNotApproved extends Exception
{
    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render the exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request)
    {
        return response()->view('errors.not_approved',['exception'=>$this],403);
    }
}


/var/www/epg_intranet/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

$response->headers->setCookie at line 159

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Exceptions\UserNotApproved;
use App\User;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class VerifyUserApproval
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->user_type == null){
            return new UserNotApproved();
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I am calling this in a middleware. W0uld that have anything to due with the error?

Comment: I think Laravel figures this stuff out for you, try `return response()->view('errors.not_approved',[],403);`

Comment: @adam you still get the same error no matter what you put in the array

Comment: Do you have a file and line number for the exception? It should be displayed with the error.

Comment: VerifyCsrfToken at line 159 I think

Comment: The report method might be wrong, the documentation has it as: `public function report()`. The definition you have is for the handler `App\Exceptions\Handler` https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors#the-exception-handler

Comment: Right now I am just trying to render the exceprion to that view.

Comment: Hmmm, looking at how laravel handles exceptions in Handler.php, I see a line: return response()->view("errors::{$status}", ['exception' => $e], $status, $e->getHeaders()); can you try to add $this->getHeaders() to the end of your response->view() call?

Comment: @NMahurin like this return response()->view('errors.not_approved',[],403)->getHeaders();

Comment: Nope, it would be: return response()->view('errors.not_approved',['exception'=>$this],403, $this->getHeaders());

Comment: Like this I still get an error return response()->view('errors.not_approved',[],403,$this->getHeaders());

Comment: Did the error change or is it the same?

Comment: The error is the same

Comment: The $request object should have a header. I'm not sure why it's not generating it automatically. You could try to manually set one: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses

Comment: Could me calling the exceprion in a middleware have anything to do with the error?

Comment: it should be `throw new UserNotApproved`

Comment: From a google search it seems like throwing an exception in middleware is a bit tricky. See https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14573 and to be honest I don't think an unauthorized user trying to access a page warrants an exception. You should just redirect the unauthorized user to a login page or something similar. This probably has to do with the fact that the middleware is ran before the session is started up, which holds the token information.

Comment: I originally had a redirect but I was basically in an infinite loop when a user wasn't approved yet

Answer (score 0):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->user_type == null){
        return new UserNotApproved();
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

A middleware is supposed to take in a response, look at it and do something, and then return a response so that the next middleware can do it's job as well.  Returning a `UserNotApproved` class is throwing this error since the next middleware is not receiving a request object.

You could do something like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->user_type == null) {
        abort(400, 'User not approved.');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

You may be able to do this as well

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->user_type == null) {
        throw new UserNotApproved();
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```